# Debug application performing transaction

Tags: mysql, transaction, client, debugging

I have an application to debug which performs a few dozen operations against a MySQL database. These operations are performed in a single transaction. I need to know the state of the database while debugging at a specific breakpoint.

I can log into the MySQL service using the common `mysql` CLI tool. I see that a transaction in progress:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM information_schema.innodb_trx\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                    trx_id: 325090
                 trx_state: RUNNING
               trx_started: 2022-09-14 12:10:32
     trx_requested_lock_id: NULL
          trx_wait_started: NULL
                trx_weight: 30
       trx_mysql_thread_id: 26
                 trx_query: NULL
       trx_operation_state: NULL
         trx_tables_in_use: 0
         trx_tables_locked: 10
          trx_lock_structs: 26
     trx_lock_memory_bytes: 1128
           trx_rows_locked: 43
         trx_rows_modified: 4
   trx_concurrency_tickets: 0
       trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
         trx_unique_checks: 1
    trx_foreign_key_checks: 1
trx_last_foreign_key_error: NULL
 trx_adaptive_hash_latched: 0
 trx_adaptive_hash_timeout: 0
          trx_is_read_only: 0
trx_autocommit_non_locking: 0
       trx_schedule_weight: NULL
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

### Now, how can I join that transaction to query the state of the database during the transaction?

As a workaround, I could add a query to the application code. However that requires me to know which query I want to run before running the application, and then to recompile the app for each query I want to run. Having an open CLI to debug would be very helpful.

The database is MySQL 8.0 running on Debian.

Comment: "*query the state of the database during the transaction*" - An uncommitted transaction hasn't actually changed anything in the database yet, and therefore IMO, the state of the database is as it was prior to when the transaction started.

Comment: @J.D. So what is the proper terminology to use to describe the situation where I might query the state of the transaction? Id est, after `BEGIN TRANSACTION; INSERT INTO foo ('bar');` I would like to query `SELECT * FROM foo` and see the `bar` row. Within the application performing transaction, using the same connection, I would see that. But logging into the `mysql` CLI I obviously don't see it. **How can I see the state of that uncommitted transaction for debugging purposes?**

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure if you can (at least not easily). I feel that would break the Isolation principle of the ACID principles of a database system. But I'm not an expert on MySQL, so can't say for sure.

Comment: Though I guess the term you're looking for is a "*dirty read*" and *maybe* the [Read Uncommitted Isolation level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_read-uncommitted) is what you're looking for.

Comment: If the transaction lasts more than a few seconds (or more than `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`), you should rethink _why_ the transaction is so slow.  That cannot be done without studying the code.  Would you like to show us the SQL in the action?

Comment: Aside from the read-uncommitted isolation level that J.D. mentioned, MySQL has no feature to allow you to inspect data as if you're in the transaction of another session. In other words, MySQL is not a debugger.

Comment: @J.D. Thank you, that seems to be exactly what I am looking for. It doesn't let me target a specific transaction, but as this is a dev environment only a single transaction is running anyway. Thank you!

Comment: @RickJames The transaction is taking time because I've stopped the application in the debugger. That is not the issue.

Comment: @BillKarwin MySQL is not a debugger, rather it is a data store. I'd like to see the data that it has stored while I'm debugging. To do that, I'd like to associate my current connection with the connection of the transaction.

Comment: @dotancohen - If you spend more than `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`, the query will be rolled back!  This could confuse your analysis.  Also, if the debugger lets you run SQL, that will probably be a disaster.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you, that timeout is critical to know about! I'm using a Jetbrains IDE as the debugger, but connecting to the MySQL server via the standard mysql-client CLI app.

Comment: @dotancohen - The default is 50 (seconds), but I think that even 5 is too large.  That is, hanging around waiting 50 seconds is likely to cause all sorts of other problems with other connections.

Comment: @RickJames: In a dev environment with no other users hitting the database, what other problems might I encounter? I've seen a few apparent Heisenbugs in the past 20 years, I would greatly appreciate any insight that you could provide about potential problems with pausing running code, in relation to DB access or otherwise. **I've always got something new to learn.** Of course, I am familiar with race conditions and timeouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User [J.D.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150011/j-d) answered in a comment, I'm putting the info here for my future self and others. If J.D. posts back with an answer, I'll accept it.

The term for reading uncommited transactions is Dirty Read. To perform a dirty read, the [Read Uncommitted Isolation level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_read-uncommitted) needs to be enabled.

```
mysql> SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

Comment: You said the extent of everything I know about it. This one's all yours. 